# session is already flushing when I use @observes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a flask app and I want to use sqlalchemy [observers](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/observers.html) to update a shipment status once all products inside that shipment become available.

Here's my datamodel:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy_utils import observes

class Shipment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shipment'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    products = db.relationship('Product', backref='shipment', lazy='dynamic')
    all_products_ready = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    @observes('products')
    def product_observer(self, products):
        for p in self.products:
            if p.status != 'ready':
                self.all_products_ready = False
                return False
        self.all_products_ready = True
        return True

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    shipment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('shipment.id'))

    status = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
```

And here is some code I run to test it:

```
shipment = models.Shipment(products=[models.Product(status='ready'), models.Product(status='not_ready')])
db.session.add(shipment)
db.session.commit()

print(shipment.all_products_ready)
```

When I run this code I get an InvalidRequestError: Session is already flushing.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    db.session.commit()
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py",
line 150, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py",
line 788, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py",
line 384, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py",
line 364, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py",
line 1985, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py",
line 2012, in _flush
    self.dispatch.before_flush(self, flush_context, objects)
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", l
ine 221, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy_utils\observer.py
", line 272, in invoke_callbacks
    for (root_obj, func, objects) in args:
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy_utils\observer.py
", line 252, in gather_callback_args
    lambda obj: obj not in session.deleted
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy_utils\functions\o
rm.py", line 741, in getdotattr
    last = [v for v in last if condition(v)]
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\dynamic.py",
line 245, in __iter__
    sess = self.session
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\dynamic.py",
line 237, in session
    sess.flush()
  File "U:\dev\observertest\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py",
line 1979, in flush
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError("Session is already flushing")
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Session is already flushing
```

How can I use my models without getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure why, but I think loading the relations using `dynamic` is causing problems here. In this line:

```
    products = db.relationship('Product', backref='shipment', lazy='dynamic')
```

you need to change the `lazy` parameter to `select` instead of `dynamic` (or you can take out the `lazy` parameter alltogether as `select` is its default).

See [the sqlalchemy reference](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html) for all the available options.

Comment: While that's helpful, I think this might still be unanswered for those of us who need to use `lazy='dynamic'`